# MacBook Pro Lion + lavalier mic records nothing

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, quicktime, microphone, recording

How can I record audio using a lavalier mic and MacBook Pro OSX Lion?

[image]
[image]

I have just opened my brand new [Audio-Technica ATR-3350 Lavalier Omnidirectional Condenser Microphone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002HJ9PTO). I tried to connect it to the jack just next to the earphones jack and record sound using quicktime player.

Recording works well without a mic, but when I connect the mic and choose `Built in input: line in` instead of `Built in Microphone: internal microphone`, only silence is recorded.

The microphone was tested on a Windows 7 notebook, and it works well.

Comment: Can you specific which Macbook you have.

Comment: Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: To test the mic you can try something like Skype, System Prefs -> Sound, etc that will show you a gauge of how much sound is being picked up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ATR3350 is not compatible with Macbook Pro. Nor is it compatible with iOS devices.
It's a turkey and I regret having bought it. The manufacturer is deliberately misleading people about this unit.

Answer (score 2):

ATR3350 is compatible with iOS devices.  I have it working on both my iphone6 and iPad Pro (9.5 inch).

At this time however it still does not work on my MacBook pro (13" Retina 2015)

Answer (score 0):

macbook air needs a lavaliere plug that has 4 sections to the plug to override Mac's attempt to only allow mac products. An inexpensive lavaliere type will work with a 4 section inexpensive plug